# The form of subrings of $k[[t]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, self-learning

> Let $H$ be a subring of $k[[t]]$ which contains all formal sums of its elements. Let $W(H)=\{i_0,i_1,i_2,\ldots\}$ be the semigroup of orders of elements in $H$, where we have $0=i_0<i_1<i_2<\cdots$. Show that for $\underline{\text{any}}$ choice of elements $S_{i_0},S_{i_1},S_{i_2},\ldots$ of elements of $H$ with $\operatorname{ord} S_{i_\ell}=i_\ell$, we have $$H=\{\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\alpha_\ell S_{i_\ell}\mid\alpha_\ell\in k\}.$$

I saw this question in an algebraic geometry book. I tried to solve this. But I did trivial thing, so I don't write what I did here. This is just self-studying. I want to learn how to solve. Please help me to solve the question. Thank you for helping.

[image]

[image]

I underlined the sentence. How to assume this $H$ is equal to that form??

Comment: Did you try letting $H$ be the closure under formal sums and ring operations of $k \cup \{p(t)\}$, where $p$ is a polynomial?

Comment: You probably need $H$ to be a $k$-subalgebra, i.e. closed under scalar multiplication by elements of $k$? If so, then you can start with an arbitrary element $h\in H$, and keep subtracting the correct multiples of $S_{i_0}$, $S_{i_1}$ et cetera, so that the remainder always has a higher order.

Comment: I don't understand what the exercise means: no subring of $k[[t]]$ contains the formal sums of its elements, and neither does $k[[t]]$. What is the formal sum of $1,1+S_1,1+S_2,\cdots$ ?

Comment: Will I posted what are written in the book as a picture? dear @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: My book says that let afiş $k$ and consider a subring of $k[[t]]$ $W(H)=\{i_0=0,i_1,i_2...\}$ be orders of the element $H$. Recall that the order of an element of $k[[t]]$ is $ord(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+...)=n$ when $a_0=....=a_{n-1}=0$ and $a_n\not=0$ In the above notation of $W(H)$ it is understood that $i_r$ is a strictly increasing squence. The set $W(H) $ is clearly a semigroup of non negative integers. If $S_0, S_{i_1},...$ are elements of H with given order, then we can write above summation. And H is that summation form. @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: Also, I posted the picture of the book above. Please help me. Please Explain. Thank you Dear @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: Dear B11b, unfortunately I can't explain anything because I don't even understand the statement! By the way from what book is this extracted?

Comment: Okay thank you for help again and again:) @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: Now that you copied the page from the book I understand this queation less! The author does not give this as an exercise nor does he claim it to be true. He just assumes that this holds. I would interpret this passage from the book as tellling that in what follows the author will only be interested in those subrings $H$ that have this closure property. At least that's how I read it.

Comment: Why would you want to prove it? It is not true for all the rings! The book doesn't claim that it is!

Comment: Do you know what it means, when we assume that something is true?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg do you have any idea for my question I posted its link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the assumption that $H$ is closed under formal sums means that if you take a sequence $h_0, h_1, h_2, \dots \in H$ such that $\text{ord}(h_0) < \text{ord}(h_1) < \dots$, then $\sum_l h_l$, which is a well-defined element of $k[[t]]$, is in fact an element of $H$.

Nevertheless, as stated, the claim is false. Consider $H = {\mathbb Z}[[t]]$. This is a subring of $k[[t]]$ that is closed under taking formal sums. We have $W(H) = \mathbb N$. Now take $S_0 = 1$, $S_1 = t$, $\dots$. Then $$\{ \sum_l \alpha_l S_l \mid \alpha_0, \alpha_1, \dots \in k \} = k[[t]] \neq {\mathbb Z}[[t]].$$

So, as already suggested by Jyrki Lahtonen, $H$ is probably supposed to be a $k$-subalgebra of $k[[t]]$. Under this assumption, it is trivial that
$$\{ \sum_l \alpha_l S_l \mid \alpha_0, \alpha_1, \dots \in k \} \subseteq H.$$
For the other direction, given an element $h$ of $H$, inductively construct a sequence $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \dots \in k$ such that for every $n \in \mathbb N$, $h$ agrees with $\sum_{i \leq n} \alpha_l S_{i_l}$ upto, at least, degree $i_n$, i.e., such that $h - \sum_{i \leq n} \alpha_l S_{i_l}$ has order greater than $i_n$. (Determine for yourself how you should pick $\alpha_{n+1}$ once you have already constructed $\alpha_0, \dots, \alpha_n$.) Then $h = \sum_k \alpha_l S_{i_l}$, showing the other inclusion.

(Note that this is just a rephrasing of the argument by Jyrki Lahtonen in the comments.)

Comment: Dear Magdiragdag, $H = {\mathbb Z}[[t]]$ is not closed under "formal sums": what is the "formal sum" of $1,1+t, 1+t+t^2,\cdots$ ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Well, I'm guessing "closed under formal sums" means "closed under adding a countably infinite sequence of ever increasing order". Otherwise, what subring would be closed under formal sums? (Well, in finite characteristic you'd have a chance) Or maybe it is supposed to mean "closed under formal sums, as long as that formal sum exists in $k[[t]]$ itself".

Comment: But, this should be true. The book gives this as a theorem. :(

Comment: I added the picture of book. Please help me this subject. Thank you.

Comment: It's exactly as I supposed. $H$ is assumed to be closed under formal sums of elements of $H$ of ever increasing order.

Comment: But,  you say this is false. But the statement should be true. I am confused Dear @Magdiragdag

Comment: I added picture of the book. Please give me more correct answer. To learn This part is important for me. :( thank you for help. But help me a little more:) @Magdiragdag

Comment: The statement is false because the author forgot the additional condition that $H$ must be a $k$-subalgebra and not just a subring (or, just maybe, somewhere the author stated that all subrings are assumed to be $k$-subalgebras). With that additional condition, it is true.

Comment: Well, I understand now. Please can you also prove the statement (true version of the statement) by assuming existing this additional condition which the writer forgot? Please. Thanks for help Dear @Magdiragdag as I said, to learn this exact proof is so important for me. I am just begining to study this topic. I need to learn properly. Thank you

Comment: You showed the Wrong part so clearly. Please continue to show the exact proof of the correct version of the statement again clearly and explicitly. @Magdiragdag

Comment: Dear Magdirag: I agree. The exercise is poorly formulated, to say the least: we shouldn't be left trying to guess what the author means.

Comment: @B11b The proof of the corrected version starts at "Under this assumption..." It's very short. I've left one very small thing there for you to do.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Indeed, it's pretty sloppy formulated.

Comment: Please you can do its proof for correct assumption. Not small please be clear and explanatory. I Try to learn this topic. Thank youu:) @Magdiragdag

Comment: +1 for this. I really don't see this exercise in the book. The way I read it is that the closure property described here is **assumed**. The claim about the properties of the semigroup of values is the interesting consequence.

Comment: @B11b So, which part are you still having trouble with?

Comment: @B11b I have shown the proof. Which part of it is not clear? I cannot guess where you could be having problems with, as you have given no indication at all.

Comment: You showed this proof under this assumption. There is a part "determine for yourself..." After there, how to be equal $h=\sum \alpha_l S_{i_l}$ here, not clear for me.

Comment: Can you clarify the last part(last two sentences)?@Magdiragdag